# Overloading '+' to add items already contained in a generic list?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, operator-overloading

I have tried to implent the functionality of merging a customer's account by overloading + operator
..
i m initially taking input in list of bankaccounts and then passing list to arguments of a function which returns a list that contains BankAccounts object.
so far i have got the list containing all accounts info related to a particular customer

but i **HAVE TO** add list items using overloading + but unable to do so .. here is my class and main code ... KINDLy Help...

```
namespace OpOverload{class BankAccounts
{
    private string title;
    List<BankAccounts> bankList = new List<BankAccounts>();
    private double balance;

    internal List<BankAccounts> BankList
    {
        get { return bankList; }
        set { bankList = value; }
    }

    public double Balance
    {
        get { return balance; }
        set { balance = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public void input()
    {
        BankAccounts[] banks = new BankAccounts[3] { new BankAccounts(), new BankAccounts(), new BankAccounts() };
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account Title?:   ");
            banks[i].Title = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Account Balance Deposited?:    ");
            banks[i].Balance = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            bankList.Add(banks[i]);
            ++i;
        } while (i <= 2);
    }

    public List<BankAccounts> setTogether(string title1, List<BankAccounts> blist)
    {
        List<BankAccounts> sameName2gther = new List<BankAccounts>();
        foreach (BankAccounts item in blist)
        {
            if (item.Title == title1)
            {
                sameName2gther.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return sameName2gther;
    }

    public static BankAccounts operator +(BankAccounts b1,List<BankAccounts> blist)
    {
        BankAccounts ba = new BankAccounts();
        foreach (BankAccounts item in blist)
        {
            ba.balance = ba.balance + item.Balance;
            ba.title = item.Title;
        }
        return ba;
    }
}
```

}

**The main code is:**

```
namespace OpOverload{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("===========Merge Accounts============");
        List<BankAccounts> customList = new List<BankAccounts>();
        BankAccounts b1 = new BankAccounts();
        BankAccounts result = new BankAccounts();
        b1.input();
        foreach (BankAccounts item in b1.BankList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title + "-->" + item.Balance);
        }
        customList = b1.setTogether("sana", b1.BankList);
        foreach (BankAccounts item in customList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title + "-->" + item.Balance);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < customList.Count; i++)
        {
            result = result + customList[i];
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why is it not working? Little more description of your problem may solve it for you. Edit: I already know your issue but i'm wondering why you can't solve it by yourself.

Comment: Error at Compile time is :Error 1 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'OpOverload.BankAccounts' and 'OpOverload.BankAccounts' c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpOverload\OpOverload\Program.cs 28 26 OpOverload

Comment: And what did this error message tells you? It tells you that you can't do `account0 + account1` but you can do `account0 + otherAccountsList`.

Comment: You only define the operator for BankAccounts and List<BankAccounts>, right?

Comment: You never "HAVE TO" unless it's homework!

Comment: no it is not home work .. practicing skills to make a final system

Comment: @banging Thats the same thing i thought. I think this question is not useful for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Define the operator + for BankAccounts and BankAccounts :-)

Comment: I have done that using List & Bank Account =)

Answer (score 1):

You defined the operator to take a `BankAccounts` and a `List<BankAccounts>`; but in your example code you tried to add together two `BankAccounts` objects.

Either redefine the operator to just add two instances, or change your usage to add a list to an instance.

Comment: I redefined the code and it worked .. thanks! =)